# How does Windows 98 run 32-bit software?

Tags: operating-system

I know Win98 is very outdated at this point but I've been curious about this for a long time.

As far as I know, Windows 98 is an OS that acts as sort of a "shell", running on top of an already existing DOS operating system. However, DOS is a 16-bit OS which cannot natively run software written for 32-bit operating systems. How does Windows 98 do it then? Is it some sort of emulation?

Comment: "Windows 95's first retail release .... and 32-bits signed integer errorlevel".[SOURCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) There was already a big part programmes using 32-bits.... Also note the 'working state' on Wikipedia: "Preserved pieces exist in 32-bit Windows"

Comment: Windows 98 was a bit more than that - it had a preemptive scheduling kernel, albeit wobbly 16-bit code that BSODed if you sneezed at it.  Since the hardware could run 32-bit code, 32- bit apps ran fine, W98 managing resources via syscalls, interrupts, thunks and frequent reboots, (well for developers, anyway).